# How to delete a file from memory using FATFS library

Tags: c, fat

I want to use elm-chen FATFS library to delete a file from memory. [this link](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_p.html). But I do not see any functions to delete a file. Is there a way to delete a file from FATFS using this library?
Thanks

Edit. I found the remove file in the full version library. The limited version does not contain the remove feature.

Comment: See on that page : "Also full featured FAT file system module is available here". Apparently you need that one if you need a full range of file operations.

Answer (score 2):

In **FatFs - Generic FAT Filesystem Module**, "Remove" means the same thing as "Delete".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you would go up one level you would find [this](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html).

It's obvious that the "*Petit FAT File System Module*" can't create nor delete files. Just do poor edits and simple reads. It's meant for "*tiny microcontrollers*" apparently.

If you want what you expect then you should follow the link above. It leads to "*FatFs - Generic FAT Filesystem Module*", it's meant for "*small embedded systems*" apparently. Which I assume you have.

---

I wish you good luck in perfecting your googling skills.

Comment: @amirmohamadhatami I can lead you to the page, but I can't make you hit "ctrl+f" for "remove". Is your thumb in the middle of your hand?

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the full version of FatFS, it contains the `f_unlink` function, which will allow you to remove files or directories. You just pass it the filename or folder to remove.